# Linq valor maximo de varias columnas de una tabla

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

soy novato en c#, necesito extraer el precio mínimo de la misma lista que contiene 4 columnas de precios y determinar de los 4 columnas de precios cual es el precio mínimo y almacenarlo en el objeto creado por Linq en el atributo CprecioMin de la clase DataProducts

Por Ejemplo el resultado de inner2 ser el siguiente de la lista, donde el dato CprecioMin me lo arroje el Linq por cada producto de la lista

*idproducto*,  *Cprecio1*,   *Cprecio2*,   *Cprecio3*,   *Cprecio 4*,  **CprecioMin**

```
   1,         21.45,     18.40,     22.50,     34.25,       **18.40**   
    2,        19.15,     20.45,     23.80,     30.80,       **19.15**   
    3,         18.30,     22.70,     12.50,     19.60,       **12.50**   
    4,         53.25,     60.55,     40.95,     34.25,       **34.25**
```

Anexo código para ser mas claro. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
    //  Clase de lstSQLP
public partial class DataProducts
    {
        public int Idproducto { get; set; }
        public string Ccodigop { get; set; }
        public string Cdescripcionp { get; set; }
        public int Cstatus { get; set; }
        public double? Cprecio1 { get; set; }
        public double? Cprecio2 { get; set; }
        public double? Cprecio3 { get; set; }
        public double? Cprecio4 { get; set; }
        public double? CprecioMin { get; set; }
    }

//  Clase de resultado
    public class GetProductosModel
    {
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string nombre { get; set; }
        public string precio1 { get; set; }
        public string precio2 { get; set; }
        public string precio3 { get; set; }
        public string precio4 { get; set; }
        public float precioMinimo { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
    }


// LinQ generado
var inner2 =
                     from a in lstSQLP
                     join b in resultado on a.Ccodigoproducto equals b.codigo
                     where a.Ccodigoproducto == b.codigo && (a.Cstatusproducto != b.status || Convert.ToString(a.Cprecio1) != b.precio1)
                     select new DataProducts {
                         Idproducto = a.Cidproducto,
                         Ccodigop = a.Ccodigoproducto,
                         Cdescripcionp = a.Cnombreproducto,
                         Cstatus = a.Cstatusproducto,
                         Cprecio1 = a.Cprecio1,
                         Cprecio2 = a.Cprecio2,
                         Cprecio3 = a.Cprecio3,
                         Cprecio4 = a.Cprecio4,
                         CprecioMin = // Prueba realizada, aqui me marca Error  CS1912  Inicialización del miembro 'CprecioMin' duplicada
                         Convert.ToSingle(from x in lstSQLP where x.Ccodigoproducto == a.Ccodigoproducto select x.Cprecio1),
             };
```

Comment: Disculpa, podrías ser mas claro con lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta, agregando un ejemplo del resultado que necesito, muchas gracias por la observación.

Comment: Una consulta cual es el propósito de ese join que realizas (por que necesitas unir esas dos listas)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aqui les dejo el codigo de como lo solucione, utilice una función, gracias a todos.

```
var lstUpdate =
                     from a in lstSQLP
                     join b in resultado on a.Ccodigoproducto equals b.codigo
                     where a.Ccodigoproducto == b.codigo && b.tkProducto != null && (a.Cstatusproducto != b.status || Convert.ToString(a.Cprecio1) != b.precio1 || Convert.ToString(a.Cprecio2) != b.precio2
                     || Convert.ToString(a.Cprecio3) != b.precio3 || Convert.ToString(a.Cprecio4) != b.precio4 || a.TkLinea != b.tkLinea || a.CNombreUnidad != b.unidad)
                     select new DataSalesupProduct
                     {
                         Idproducto = a.Cidproducto,
                         Ccodigop = a.Ccodigoproducto,
                         Cdescripcionp = a.Cnombreproducto,
                         Cstatus = a.Cstatusproducto,
                         Cprecio1 = a.Cprecio1,
                         Cprecio2 = a.Cprecio2,
                         Cprecio3 = a.Cprecio3,
                         Cprecio4 = a.Cprecio4,
                         CprecioMin = Fpreciomin(Convert.ToSingle(a.Cprecio1), Convert.ToSingle(a.Cprecio2), Convert.ToSingle(a.Cprecio3), Convert.ToSingle(a.Cprecio4)),
                     };


    private static float Fpreciomin (float pprecio1, float pprecio2, float pprecio3, float pprecio4)
    {
        float[] vpremin = { Convert.ToSingle(pprecio4), Convert.ToSingle(pprecio3), Convert.ToSingle(pprecio2), Convert.ToSingle(pprecio1) };
        IEnumerable<float> lstmin = (from r in vpremin
                                     orderby r
                                     where r != 0
                                     select r).Take(1);
        float vcpreciomin = 1f;
        foreach (float l in lstmin)
        {
            vcpreciomin = l;
        }
        return vcpreciomin;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En tu linq prueba a poner esto:

```cs
var inner2 =
                     from a in lstSQLP
                     join b in resultado on a.Ccodigoproducto equals b.codigo
                     let min = Math.Min(Math.Min(Math.Min(a.Cprecio1 ?? double.MaxValue, a.Cprecio2 ?? double.MaxValue), a.Cprecio3 ?? double.MaxValue), a.Cprecio4 ?? double.MaxValue)
                     where a.Ccodigoproducto == b.codigo && (a.Cstatusproducto != b.status || Convert.ToString(a.Cprecio1) != b.precio1)
                     select new DataProducts {
                         Idproducto = a.Cidproducto,
                         Ccodigop = a.Ccodigoproducto,
                         Cdescripcionp = a.Cnombreproducto,
                         Cstatus = a.Cstatusproducto,
                         Cprecio1 = a.Cprecio1,
                         Cprecio2 = a.Cprecio2,
                         Cprecio3 = a.Cprecio3,
                         Cprecio4 = a.Cprecio4,
                         CprecioMin = min,
             };
```

Si el valor viene a null le da el valor máximo para que no lo tenga en cuenta. Si quieres que si es null ponga 0 cambia double.MaxValue a 0

Comment: Hola @Sentach, me marca esto CS0019 El operador '??' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'double' y 'double' e intente con el operador ??= y tampoco me lo permite. –

Comment: Si es de tipo double en vez de tipo double? quita "?? 0" esto sirve en los tipos que pueden ser null evitar que sean null

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, lo solucione con una Función creada por mi, ya que no puede hacer que no considerara el 0 como valor mínimo del codigo que me pasaste, Te agradezco mucho por tus comentarios ya que aprendi nuevas funciones como let y el min.